# IDS/IPS payload analysis

Tags: ids

While reading about IDS/IPS systems it is often mentioned that they analyze the "payload information of a packet" but what "payload" do they exactly look at?

[image]

Comment: In general payload is referrer to the Data depending on the network layer are you taking. For example , form TCP the payload will be the data (in your image) and in the case that you are referring payload on the IP layer will be the TCP segment.

Comment: @camp0 yes, it says as much in the image: there are 3 payloads. The question is which one does it look at

Comment: Different IDS/IPS will look at different things. Snort, a famous IDS, can look at Ethernet, IP, and TCP payloads: each one of the payloads in your image

Comment: @schroeder okay, that makes sense. One question though. I was looking at Snort and it looks like it does not support decryption. If I'm not mistaken signature based detection would not work in that case since the payload is encrypted. What can an IDS/IPS possibly do with encrypted packets (perform network analysis based on L2,3,4 addressing information?) to detect anomalies?